# Acquire access token via oAuth from Azure Active Directory

Tags: apex, oauth2, jwt, crypto, azure-active-directory

I'm using `Crypto.signWithCertificate` with a certificate in the `Certificate and Key Management` area.   The platform I'm accessing (AAD) requires thumbprint of the certificate as part of the `client credentials (bearer) flow with certificate signing` access token request.  Unfortunately, unless I'm wrong, `Auth.JWT`, `Auth.JWS`, and `Auth.JWTBearerTokenExchange` classes are incompatible.  I would rather not have to persist the thumbprint, but derive or retrieve it from the system in runtime.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! How did you determine that `Auth.JWT`, `Auth.JWS`, and `Auth.JWTBearerTokenExchange` are incompatible?  Please take a moment to read [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour).  Including a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks!  By testing it and looking at what it does and reading the documentations.  They don't provide access to modify the token header or the form parameters.  They do allow modification of the claims of the token payload, but that's not enough.  It needs a very specific unusual set of form parameters.   In addition, MS documentation explains what a particular header should be: the base64url encoded cert thumbprint, but the helper sets that value to the name of the certificate in SF.  Sorry I'm not at my workstation right now or I would provide code, output examples, and links.

Comment: Unfortunately the thumbprint isn't available via SF platform, storing it is the way to go. MS's implementation of JWT bearer with client creds (RFC 7523) is good except for the `kid`/`x5t` nuance.

Comment: Thanks,  please make that an answer and I'll accept it.